# mysql md5(md5('pass') + salt) not equal php md5(md5('pass').salt)

Tags: php, mysql, md5

MySql query:

```
select md5(md5('pass') + '123') from foo
```

gives c8ffe9a587b126f152ed3d89a146b445 
while php `md5(md5('pass').'123')`
gives
ae2553fb5786e36233d25c879faf3863

What is wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select md5(CONCAT(md5('pass'), '123'))
```

`+` is probably adding it.

Comment: Is is adding it; the concat will fix the OP's problem. That being said ... MD5 for passwords? Really? You can calculate 400 million+ PER SECOND with a GPU based cracker in order to brute force passwords.

Comment: @Erik: To someone bruteforce a MD5 hash to get a password to use in a given website, you first need to have the MD5 hash, and the salt, and a 400 million tests/sec GPU based cracker. So it doesn't really metter here sinse in a first instance only the website developer will have two of those tree items, and this same developer could just choose to not encrypt stuff and have the password at any time without effort.

Comment: @Havenard - If it doesn't matter, why not use SHA1, which is supported in MySQL and in PHP with zero extra effort?

Comment: SHA1 has the same implication, its just 32 bits longer. For bruteforce the encryption used doesnt metter so far you know what encryption was used, unless it requires some salt or key you don't have.

Comment: BTW, some say its safer to generate the md5 hash in your code then in the database, because the SQL query will carry the password unprotected to the MySQL Server and may be vulnerable to a "middle man" attack.

Comment: @havenard - databases including the salt get compromised fairly often all things considered. It's trivial to do it right, so why wouldn't you do it right?

Answer (score 4):

That's not how you concatenate strings in MySQL. See for yourself: `SELECT 'pass' + '123';`

Instead try `SELECT md5(concat(md5('pass'), '123')) from foo`